# How to using multiple object maps in the same test suite (squish)?

Tags: squish, testautomationfx

I try to build up a usable framework for squish based test cases. Actually it uses one gigantic Object map, which is surely not works later. So, I wanted to split the text based Object map to several script based, according to a logic, but some of them need to be accessible from each test suite.

My problem, that in some case the same test suite would use more then one Object map... if I split it into more, squish doesn't recognize them, and gives me a lookup error, but creates always (even if I delete it / rename it) the names.py script file. If I copy there my objects, it works. But with a custom name (eg. custom_name_map.py) doesn't work.. I didn't found any solution on Froglogic or on QT sits/videos, and in test suite settings I cannot select the default object map, only the fallback object map (which is my custom_name_map.py) In the suite.conf the OBJECTMAP = custom_name_map.py

*suite_example

- /shared
- ```
     /scripts
  ```
- ```
         custom_name_common_map.py
  ```
- ```
         names.py
  ```
- ```
         names.pyc (?????? what is  this? cannot be opened)
  ```
- ```
     /steps
  ```
- ```
         example_steps.py
  ```
- /tst-example
- ```
     /**suite_tst_example_1**
  ```
- ```
         /shared
  ```
- ```
             /scripts
  ```
- ```
                 names.py - **works only if here defined the object map, cannot use custom_name_common map**
               names.pyc
  ```

Comment: Script based object names in modern Squish are just script files. What and how they can be used, split up, loaded, imported, etc. depends on the scripting language. Squish will, as far as I know, always add object names to the default names.py file. The reasons for the split up are not clear to me. I recommend to discuss this with the vendor of Squish. If you want to discuss here, I recommend to elaborate on motivation and requirements. (*.pyc files are specific to Python, they are the preprocessed/parsed variant of the corresponding *.py file, for sake it optimization. Usually ignore these.)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is new at squish+python :p:

1. .pyc is a cashed python file, do not care about it...
2. names.py is always where squish searching the object map. You can split into several different files as common.py and special_to_this_scenario.py, but you need to import them into names (avoiding circular reference) - so squish will see it together as one big object map, relates to the actual test suite.